# Каким образом увеличить размер карты в режиме панорам?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

У меня стартовый пример от yandex, где main div с параметром width: 600px. И в таком размере с панорамами все хорошо. Но если я делаю карту по всей ширине экрана и высоте, в режиме панорам окошко карты уменьшается до размера(300/180). Как добиться визуализации как на основной странице Яндекс карт? А именно: в режиме панорам, окно мини карты растягивается на 100% по ширине.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мини-карта подстраивается под размер контейнера, растянуть её нельзя.